# Confused about useNavigation vs Context

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am new to react native and want to ask simple question about React Context vs useNavigation, as i am concerned that both of these can pass information to child object but useNavigation is simple to use so can i use useNavigation in place of Context? any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`useNavigation` is a hook which gives access to navigation object. It's useful when you cannot pass the navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

`useContext` is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.

You should read the documentation about React Hooks (for Context) and React Navigation. But it's two different notion and they have different use cases.

But simply, a Context is a global state you can use thru different components. `useNavigation` give access to the navigation Context.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is no comparison between [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/), `useNavigation` is [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) part of [react-navigation-5](https://reactnavigation.org)  It's useful when you cannot pass the navigation prop into the component directly.
but `Context` is build-in `react` to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components`.

your question must be :

#### difference between `(the way that useNavigation work to pass navigation down)` vs `Context`?

the answer in **no difference**.

because the way that useNavigation use to pass navigation down is `Context`
, it is `custom hooks with Context`.
if you see useNavigation [source in github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/useNavigation.tsx).

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import NavigationContainerRefContext from './NavigationContainerRefContext';
import NavigationContext from './NavigationContext';
import type { NavigationProp } from './types';


export default function useNavigation<T = NavigationProp<ReactNavigation.RootParamList>
>(): T {

  //if you see here it work based on context
  const root = React.useContext(NavigationContainerRefContext);
  const navigation = React.useContext(NavigationContext);

  if (navigation === undefined && root === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?"
    );
  }

  // FIXME: Figure out a better way to do this
  return (navigation ?? root) as unknown as T;
}
```